# A Function that Detects whether the first half of a string matches the second half - Homework Warning JS

Tags: javascript, string

I have this homework question and I cant figure out a good way of checking.  I have went down the path of indexOf and string.repeat(), but just not getting what the question is looking for.  I could do a reg ex, but since this is basic javascript I would like know how to do it without going there.

Question:
Write a function named repeats that returns true if the first half
of the string equals the last half, and false if not

Example:

If you pass it "haha" then it should return true because "ha" (the first half) equals
"ha" (the second half)
If you pass it "yay" then it should return false because it's odd
If you pass it "heehaw" then it should return false because "hee" doesn't equal "haw"
*/

This is what I have so far after many attempts at looping and methods:

```
var stringEq = "haha";
var stringNoEq = "heehaw";

function stringEqual(string) {

    if (string.length % 2 !== 0) {
        return false;
      }
      else{
        string.length /2 
      }

    }

    stringEqual(stringEq)
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just get the first half of the string and the second half and return `firstHalf === secondHalf`?

Answer (score 0):

```
function stringEqual(myString) {
    if (myString.length % 2 != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    var firstHalf = myString.substr(0, myString.length/2);
    var secondHalf = myString.substr(myString.length/2);

    return firstHalf == secondHalf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function halfStringAreEqual(string str){
    if (str.length % 2 != 0)
        return false;

    var half = str.length / 2;

    return str.substr(0, half) == str.substr(half, str.length - half);
}
```